# reduce ticks of matplotlib axis

Tags: python, matplotlib, reduce, axis

I have a question. I would like to show on a plot a few values and dates.
but the axes are very full...
is there a possibility to display only a part of the values on the axes?
So a possibility to reduce the values to e.g. 5 ?

```
for kurs in kurs_daten[:20]:
       datum.append(kurs.split(",")[0])
       kurse.append(kurs.split(",")[1][:5])

print(kurse)
print(datum)

plt.plot(datum,kurse)
plt.xlabel("Datum")

plt.ylabel("Kurs")
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Actually, first thing to fix would be to change your data to ints or floats from the strings they currently are.

Comment: good Idea I changed something now it looks a little bit better :)

Answer (score -1):

You can rotate your labels on the x-axis

plt.xticks(rotation = 45)  will rotate 45 degrees

rotate 90 degrees for vertical

Comment: How does this answer the question?

Comment: If the tick labels were displayed vertically or at a 45 degree angle, you would not have to reduce the number of ticks.  It's a simple alternative that may or may not help.